# getting this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this site and to python.  I'm working on a web scraping project to return all of the url links from a website and using a for loop to parse only the url link.  Here's my code:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

This code above works and returns 663 tags with href attribute.

```
records = []

for result in links:
    url = links['href']
    records.append(url)
```

When I run this for loops i get the list indices error must be integers or slicers, not str

What can i do to correct this?

Thanks,
Garrett

Comment: I think you need `result['href']`

Comment: `url = result['href']`

Comment: thanks so much this fixed it!